# I am getting 414 Request URI too long in facebook oauth?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am using a apache server, the default LimitRequestLine is 8190. On getting a callback from Facebook for oauth. I am getting 414 Request URI too long from apache?

Is this normal? shouldn't facebook taking care of the uri length? My actual callback uri is /login/callback?auth=.

Apache dosent allow LimitRequestLine > 8190 without recompiling it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide more info. Never heard this kinda error with facebook api earlier!

Comment: Most likely a problem with you Apache server...